# Smoothing multiple columns with Hann window - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have:

```
hann10=hanning(10);
b = repmat(hann10,[1 5]);
smooth10=conv(fragments,b,'same');
```

However this throws the error:

```
Error using conv (line 27)
A and B must be vectors.
```

I essentially want to smooth `fragments` which contains multiple but equally sized columns (i.e. 100x5) by the same hann window, separately - applying the window to each column as if it was a separate vector.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) convolves column-wise if you give it a column as a second argument. So just use:

```
smooth10 = conv2(fragments, hann10, 'same');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well probably using a for:

```
hann10=hanning(10);
for ii=1:size(fragments,2)
   smooth10(ii,:)=conv(fragments(:,ii),hann10,'same');
end
```